# OpenGL Texture Array sometimes initializes with GL_TEXTURE_2D

Tags: java, opengl, textures, lwjgl

So i have switched from a normal texture atlas stitcher to an array texture since it's easier to handle when using mipmapping and greedy meshing.
The problem I'm having is, that even though the arrays are all generated with the same function, my normal and specular arrays have a wrong texture state. The only difference between the diffuse array and the normal/specular is that the diffuse array uses GL_RGBA and the normal/specular array GL_RGB.

This is the method i use to generate an array:

```
@Override
public void init(int layerCount, boolean supportsAlpha, int textureSize) {
    this.textureId = glGenTextures();
    this.maxLayer = layerCount;
    this.mipmap = Client.getInstance().getConfig().getGraphics().isMipmap();
    this.anisotropicLevel = OpenGLThread.getInstance().isAnisotropicSupported() ? Client.getInstance().getConfig().getGraphics().getAnisotropicFiltering() : 0;

    int internalFormat = supportsAlpha ? GL_RGBA8 : GL_RGB8;
    this.format = supportsAlpha ? GL_RGBA : GL_RGB;

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, this.textureId);
    glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, internalFormat, textureSize, textureSize, layerCount, 0, this.format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    int errorCode = glGetError();
    if (errorCode != 0) LOGGER.error("Error while generating texture array. {}", GLHelper.errorToString(errorCode));
}
```

When I generate the diffuse atlas, renderdoc tells me the following information about the texture:

> internalformat GL_RGBA8
>   isView         False
>   width          32
>   height         32
>   depth          278
>   samples        0
>   dim            3
>   type           GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY
>   mips           1
>   baseLevel      0
>   maxLevel       1000
>   minLod         -1000.00
>   maxLod         1000.00
>   srgbDecode     GL_DECODE_EXT
>   depthMode      GL_NONE
>   compareFunc    GL_LEQUAL
>   compareMode    GL_NONE
>   minFilter      GL_NEAREST
>   magFilter      GL_NEAREST

Which works fine, because the type is GL_TEXTURE_2d_ARRAY like i defined.
When generating the other two atlases (order doesn't matter btw) renderdoc tells me the following information:

> internalformat GL_RGB8
>   isView         False
>   width          1
>   height         1
>   depth          278
>   samples        0
>   dim            3
>   type           GL_TEXTURE_2D
>   mips           1
>   baseLevel      0
>   maxLevel       0
>   minLod         0.00
>   maxLod         0.00
>   srgbDecode     GL_NONE
>   depthMode      GL_NONE
>   compareFunc    GL_NONE
>   compareMode    GL_NONE
>   minFilter      GL_NONE
>   magFilter      GL_NONE

Which is something completely different even though the same method was used. Even if i switch the two atlases to RGBA they do not work and i don't understand why openGL suddenly decides to use a different parameter then specified in the glTexImage3D() method.

This is the method which adds new texture layers, if it helps:

```
@Override
public void upload(ITextureLayer textureLayer) {
    if (textureLayer.getLayer() >= this.maxLayer) {
        LOGGER.error("Tried uploading a texture with a too big layer.");
        return;
    } else if (this.textureId == 0) {
        LOGGER.error("Tried uploading texture layer to uninitialized texture array.");
        return;
    }

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, this.textureId);

    // Tell openGL how to unpack the RGBA bytes
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    // Upload the texture data
    glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, textureLayer.getLayer(), textureLayer.getWidth(), textureLayer.getHeight(), 1, this.format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureLayer.getPixels());

    if (this.mipmap) {
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        if (this.anisotropicLevel > 0) {
            float amount = Math.min(this.anisotropicLevel, glGetFloat(EXTTextureFilterAnisotropic.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT));
            glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, EXTTextureFilterAnisotropic.GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, amount);
        } else {
            glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_LOD_BIAS, -1);
        }
    } else {
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    }

    int errorCode = glGetError();
    if (errorCode != 0) LOGGER.error("Error while uploading texture layer {} to graphics card. {}", textureLayer.getLayer(), GLHelper.errorToString(errorCode));
}
```

Comment: Is there some change in the texture unit specified with `glActiveTexture` between those two logs?

Comment: No. The atlases are generated directly after each other and since they all need to be generated in the same thread because of OpenGL's lack of multithreading support there can't be any calls to glActiveTexture until the arrays are all fully generated.

Comment: What are the actual values for `textureSize` and `layerCount`, in the case which seems to fail?

Comment: textureSize is 1 because i don't actually have normal textures and therefore i just copy a static bytebuffer with just a single pixel in it, which works fine when exporting every layer as png. layercount is 278

Comment: Oh, just read in the documentation that the minimum size is 16

Comment: But even if i increase the texture size to 32 like in the diffuse array the array still has the type GL_TEXTURE_2D and has wrong LOD and mipmap settings